# How to make a table to load a list or array in Applescript-ObjC?

Tags: applescript-objc

I need to make a table in a Applescript project, but I don't know how to make a table...

```
on myTable_(sender)

set myTable to {"Hello","World"}

end myTable_
```

Comment: Hi is a "NSTable view" in Xcode

Comment: You could have a look at [Myriad Tables Lib](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/Script_Libs.html#MyriadTablesLib)

Comment: I need to create a table in Xcode not in the script editor.

Comment: OK, these are details that are missing from your question, which you should include if you want to get effective help.  As I do no use XCode, I’m afraid I cannot assist you in this instance.  Hopefully, someone else can.